# React useEffect for Loading Data

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React Hooks and I'm wondering what would be the most effective way to reload data while being "hook friendly".

I've identified 3 use cases (the latest apparently being the "more appropriate"

With Copied Code

```
//Example of Using useEffect Hooks by duplicating code
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
  const [deals, setDeals] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://localhost:1338/deals`
    }).then(res => {
      setDeals(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }, [setDeals])
  return(
    <div className="Deals">
      {loading &&
        <p>It's loading</p>
      }
      {!loading &&
        <>
          {deals.map((deal, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="Deal Note">
              {deal.label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      }

      <button onClick={() => {
          setLoading(true)
          axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `http://localhost:1338/deals`
          }).then(res => {
            setDeals(res.data)
            setLoading(false)
          }).catch(res => {
            setDeals([{label: 1, label: 2}])
            setLoading(false)
          })
      }}>Fetch Again</button>

    </div>
  )
}
```

By Passing Hooks inside an external function. Code reuse - using hooks inside another function
I'm understanding this is not "the way" to use hooks although this was my first go-to solution

```
//Example of Using useEffect Hooks by feeding hooks to external function
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const usefetchMore = (setDeals, setLoading) => {
  console.log("usefetchMore")
  setLoading(true)
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://localhost:1338/deals`
  }).then(res => {
    setDeals(res.data)
    setLoading(false)
  })
}

export default () => {
  const [deals, setDeals] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    usefetchMore(setDeals, setLoading)
  }, [setDeals])

  return(
    <div className="Deals">
      {loading &&
        <p>It's loading</p>
      }
      {!loading &&
        <>
          {deals.map((deal, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="Deal Note">
              {deal.label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      }

      <button onClick={() => usefetchMore(setDeals, setLoading)}>Fetch Again</button>

    </div>
  )
}
```

This one seem to be "the proper way of doing it" and is based on having `useEffect` re-triggered because it's listening to the changes on the `reload` variable which is there just to re-trigger it.

```
//Example of Using useEffect Hooks with variable to re-trigger useEffect
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
/* DOESN't WORK */
export default () => {
  const [deals, setDeals] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Deal4.useEffect")
    setLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://localhost:1338/deals`
    }).then(res => {
      setDeals(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }, [setDeals, reload])
  return(
    <div className="Deals">
      {loading &&
        <p>It's loading</p>
      }
      {!loading &&
        <>
          {deals.map((deal, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="Deal Note">
              {deal.label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      }

      <button onClick={() => {
          setReload(reload + 1)
      }}>Fetch Again</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**My question is: If I were to build a component that shows loading and allows to refresh itself, which way would be the proper way to write it with "React hooks"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a component in /src/ called Photos.js and give it a basic list:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./hooks";

function Photos() {
  const [data, loading] = useFetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=1"
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Photos</h1>
      {loading ? (
        "Loading..."
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.map(({ id, title, url }) => (
            <li key={`photo-${id}`}>
              <img alt={title} src={url} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Photos;
```

**Now we need a Hook! Create a file in the same directory called hooks.js and fill it with this:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  async function fetchUrl() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
    setLoading(false);
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);
 
  return [data, loading];
}

 export { useFetch };
```

**Import the Photos component into App.js and yarn start. Done!**