# Render static HTML before getServerSideProps return

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a nextjs page that has some static html and one table that fetchs data from a database. Right now when I navigate to this page it only shows up after the database return its data.

I want to show the data immediately upon the user navigate to the page and then I can wait to fill the table with data.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {

        console.log('Fetching AWS data');
        // Fetch the data...
        return { props: { rowData: response } }
    }

export default function Digest({ rowData }) {

    return <>
        // I want to render this h1 tag below
        // before the getServerSideProps returns its values
        <h1>Newsletter</h1>  
        <NewsletterTable rowData={rowData} />
    </>
    }
```

Comment: `getServerSideProps` will always run before `Digest`. Consider fetching on the front-end instead (inside the component)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm gonna try to move this logic to the component. Maybe a `useEffect`hook? sorry these are my first steps in nextjs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830374/react-useeffect-for-loading-data