# How to add loading state in React while useEffect is processing synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got an app with 2 values that user can change stored as state. When they're changed I do some processing in useEffect and also store output of this processing in state and render it.

At this point everything is working perfectly fine, but this processing takes some time and I want to show some loading indicator. **I want it to show after button click.**

This is simplified version of my app and dumb implementation of this loading indicator - I know why this doesn't work, I just don't know how to write it correctly so I made this just to show what I'm trying to do. Here is the code:

```
function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // setting true here won't work,
  // because I want to show loading indicator after user change value1 or value2
  // and not on inital load

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1999999999; i++) {} // some long operations
    setOutput(value1 + value2);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [value1, value2]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue1(value1 + 1)}>increment value1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue2(value2 + 1)}>increment value2</button>
      <div>
        {value1} + {value2} = {isLoading ? 'please wait...' : output}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If it's a non-async truly "long" operation you're likely better off throwing it into a worker and using a response message to unset the loading state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useEffect for Loading Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830374/react-useeffect-for-loading-data)

Comment: Also if it's non-async I **think** you could also queue up the long-running part w/ a `setTimeout` or `queueMicrotask` (or whatever the modern setTimeout(0) is; I don't recall atm) w/ the long-running part as the function. **But** it's better off in a worker so the UX doesn't suffer. If it's async then it should be handled normally.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. This is very simple app, this useEffect is essentialy the only thing it's doing, I want to keep this as simple as possible. In vanilla JS that would be the easiest thing in the world, there's really no simple way to make this in React?

Comment: … simpler than typing `setTimeout(longRunningOp, 0)`? No, probably nothing much simpler . If it’s a very simple app why are you using React? Setting state is async; this is beneficial, but it sounds like React is not particularly useful in this case.

Comment: (Not that a worker is much harder, and that approach doesn’t trash the main thread, React or not.)

Comment: @DaveNewton setTimeout method work just like other proposed solutions - there's old output during the calculations and loading shows for just a split second before new output. And I use React in this project just for sake of learning React - this is my first app in React

Comment: Then I guess you’re left with the worker solution, which is better anyway as the main thread isn’t blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the value of isLoading equals true, so, the page will start on loading.

```
function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1999999999; i++) {} // some long operations
    setOutput(value1 + value2);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [value1, value2]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue1(value1 + 1)}>increment value1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue2(value2 + 1)}>increment value2</button>
      <div>
        {value1} + {value2} = {isLoading ? 'please wait...' : output}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It solves problem only on page load, but not on button click

Comment: You can continue with `setIsLoading(true);` at the beginning of useEffect, and then it will start loading when the button is clicked

Comment: @RondleyGregório That's the original code--since `setState` is async it won't work as expected, which is what the OP is asking. My comments provide two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
<div>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setValue1(value1 + 1);
    }}
  >
    increment value1
  </button>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setValue2(value2 + 1);
    }}
  >
    increment value2
  </button>
```

Complete code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hill-jy1bfm?file=/src/App.js:689-1018

Comment: I already tried this but it also doesn't work correctly. There's still old output during the calculations and loading shows only on split second before new output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is asynchronous. There may be many different approaches to the solution, but for your simple example I have simple solution:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState(0);
  const isLoading = value1 + value2 !== output;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      console.log(1);
    } // some long operations
    setOutput(value1 + value2);
  }, [value1, value2]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue1(value1 + 1)}>increment value1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue2(value2 + 1)}>increment value2</button>
      <div>
        {value1} + {value2} = {isLoading ? "please wait..." : output}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Same as other answer here - it shows old output during the calculations and shows loading only on split second before new output.

Comment: Also in real app the calculations are much more advanced, I can't just check isLoading = value1 + value2 !== output

Comment: And I would also stand by saying it's synchronous - if instead of doing this processing I would for example fetch data my initial solution would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that between setting `isLoading` to `true` and setting it back to `false` (after the calculation-heavy operation) no rendering happened.

Several approaches now come to my mind; and I'm not sure which one actually works as expected and (from those that do) which one I would pick; so I just share what's on my mind:

- approach 1 (adding it to the task queue of the main thread): only setting the loading flag synchronously (and thus returning from user code and handing the control flow back to the current render-run of react), and deliberately triggering the calculation in an asynchronous way

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) return;
    setIsLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const result = heavyCalculation(value1, value2);
      setOutput(result);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [value1, value2]);
  ```
- approach 2 (adding it to the microtask queue of the main thread): turn it into micro tasks (a.k.a. Promises): when your useEffect just creates and starts a promise object and then "forgets" about it, the control flow is handed back to react. when a promise resolves and changes your component state react will do a re-render. But I suspect this might not bring any change, because afaik the microtask queue runs on the main thread and will run until empty, before react can schedule the re-rendering task. Disclaimer: promises are not my strong suit and I might have fudged that up here.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) return;
    setIsLoading(true);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        const result = heavyCalculation(value1, value2);
        setOutput(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [value1, value2]);
  ```
- approach 3 (using [flushSync](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/flushSync)): ensuring the UI is rendered before your next statement. you are not allowed to call flushSync inside useEffect, therefore you need to place the call inside a new task or microtask

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) return;

    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => flushSync(() => setIsLoading(true)))
      .then(() => {
        const result = heavyCalculation(value1, value2);
        setOutput(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [value1, value2]);
  ```

  or

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!value1 && !value2) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
      flushSync(() => setIsLoading(true));
      const result = heavyCalculation(value1, value2);
      setOutput(result);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [value1, value2]);
  ```

Comment: None of this options work. Using setTimeout keeps old output during the calculations and flashes loading for a split second before showing new output. Using promise don't change anything

Comment: It might be worth your while to try to move the long running code into a webworker; then it is off your main thread and can't clog up your rendering. There is even a lib ([comlink](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink)) that makes using webworkers a bit easier.